# Unique values horizontally every *n cell (Gsheets)

Tags: google-sheets, unique, offset, transpose

I am trying to convert unique values of vertical range to horizontal however I wish to have the output every second cell (*see desired output on the image*). I have tried offset() and mod() function however it does not seem to work. Could you please give me a clue of how to modify my function?

Function:
`=unique(transpose(T2:T10))`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula

`=transpose(flatten(query(unique(T2:T10),"select Col1, ' ' label ' ''' ") ))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution you can go with by using `SPLIT`, `JOIN`, `CONCATENATE`, `REPT` and `ARRAYFORMULA` and it gives you easier way to adjust for `every n cells` by just changing a number of many cells you want skipped.

#### Formula for 1 cell skipped:

- `=SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(CONCATENATE(REPT(", ", 1), ",") ,UNIQUE(A2:A10))),",")`
- Change `1` inside `REPT` function to choose how many cells are to be skipped

#### Behavior:

- Repeats the ", "  via `REPT` and pair with a comma at the end using `CONCATENATE`
- Joins the `UNIQUE(A2:A10)` with the delimiter generated above via `JOIN` in an `ARRAYFORMULA` (resulting to `1, ,2, ,3, ,4...`)
- Lastly, `SPLIT` by `","`, thus having a blank cell in between the numbers (These blank cells are those spaces in between commas we inserted)

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: hi @mromankim, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

My simple approach is:

`=arrayformula(split(join(",,",unique(T4:T10)),",",1,0))`

Then `JOIN` puts them in a line, separated by two commas.

`SPLIT` pushes them into different columns. The 'remove_empty_text' parameter in `SPLIT` is set to false `0`, following the 'split_by_each' parameter `1`. This splits by **each** comma in the join. Hence, `",,,"` would be two spaces apart.

If you need to ignore gaps, then wrap a query around the data range:

`query({T4:T10},"where Col1 is not null",0)`

The `query` can also sort the results:

`query({T4:T10},"where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0)`

So the final formula would be:

`=arrayformula(split(join(",,",unique(query({T4:T10},"where Col1 is not null order by Col1",0))),",",1,0))`